# Create log alert rule through powershell and attach more than one action groups to that rule

Tags: azure, powershell

I want to create an  metric alert rule and add two existing action groups to that rule through PowerShell . I got some code from azure docs that describes how to create and attach a new action group to an alert rule. Help me , if you know ! (Remember, I want to attach existing action groups)

Comment: what's your code of create metric alert rule?

Comment: Add-AzMetricAlertRule    -Name $Name 
                                         -WindowSize $windowSize 
       -Operator $operator 
       -Threshold $threshold 
       -TargetResourceId $scope 
       -MetricName $metricName 
       -TimeAggregationOperator 'Total' 
       -Location $Location  
       -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroupName 
       -Description $description 
       -Action "???"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you are using `Add-AzMetricAlertRule`, if so, I don't think you can add action group to it. The command will create `metric alert(classic)`, its resource type is `Microsoft.Insights/alertRules`, it does not support to use action group. The `-Action` parameter which you can see is to set action(email, webhook), not action group. If you check the rule in the portal, you can also find there is nowhere to set action group.

[image]

If you want to use action group, you need to create the new metric alert rule, its resource type is `Microsoft.Insights/metricAlerts`. For the new metric alert rule, seems there is no built-in powershell command, we need to use an ARM template and `New-AzResourceGroupDeployment` to create it. See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-metric-create-templates

You can find the `actions` in the template, just specific the `actionGroupId`, you will be able to add the action group.

```
"actions": [
                    {
                        "actionGroupId": "[parameters('actionGroupId')]"
                    }
                ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the new cmdlet in updated Az.Monitor module - it has `ActionGroup` parameter:

```
NAME                                                                                                                                                                          
    Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2                                                                                                                                                   

SYNOPSIS                                                                                                                                                                      
    Adds or updates a V2 (non-classic) metric-based alert rule.                                                                                                               


SYNTAX                                                                                                                                                                        
    Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -ActionGroup <Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ActivityLogAlertActionGroup[]> -Condition                                                 
    <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.OutputClasses.PSMetricCriteria]> [-DefaultProfile                                                    
    <Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.Core.IAzureContextContainer>] [-Description <System.String>] [-DisableRule] -Frequency <System.TimeSpan>     
    -Name <System.String> -ResourceGroupName <System.String> -Severity <System.Int32> -TargetResourceId <System.String> -WindowSize <System.TimeSpan> [-Confirm] [-WhatIf]    
    [<CommonParameters>]                                                                                                                                                      

    Add-AzMetricAlertRuleV2 -ActionGroup <Microsoft.Azure.Management.Monitor.Models.ActivityLogAlertActionGroup[]> -Condition                                                 
    <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Insights.OutputClasses.PSMetricCriteria]> [-DefaultProfile                                                    
    <Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.Core.IAzureContextContainer>] [-Description <System.String>] [-DisableRule] -Frequency <System.TimeSpan>     
    -Name <System.String> -ResourceGroupName <System.String> -Severity <System.Int32> -TargetResourceRegion <System.String> -TargetResourceScope <System.String[]>            
    -TargetResourceType <System.String> -WindowSize <System.TimeSpan> [-Confirm] [-WhatIf] [<CommonParameters>]                                                               


DESCRIPTION                                                                                                                                                                   
    Adds or updates a V2 (non-classic) metric-based alert rule . The added rule is associated with a resource group and has a name. This cmdlet implements the ShouldProcess  
    pattern, i.e. it might request confirmation from the user before actually creating, modifying, or removing the resource.
```